# About Login page that I created using asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms, ado.net

I created a website for my class project but I have difficulty of creating login. I insert my data to the database using parameter. I'm doing it in c# and my database in sql server.

first I create login procedure:

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[uselogin]
    @userNickName nvarchar(50),
    @userPassword nchar(10)
  As 
    SELECT [userId]
      ,[userFirstName]
      ,[userLastName]
      ,[userNickName]
      ,[userPassword]
      ,[userStreetAddress]
      ,[userEmail]
  FROM [dbo].[User_T]
  WHERE userNickName=@userNickName AND userPassword=@userPassword
```

Then in the login page I create login textbox and login button Like this:

```html
  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Username: "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtuserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control "></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="form-control "></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogIn" runat="server" Text="Log In " onClick="button_login_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
```

Code behind the aspx page

```
protected void button_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtuserName.Text;
        string userPassoword = txtPassword.Text;

        User user = new User(userName, userPassoword);
        cc.userLogin(user);
    }
```

Here is my C# code and all the classes I used:

```
Class User{
string name;
string userName;
string usePass;
.........
.....
public User(string un, string pass)
{
 this.UserNickName = un;
 this. UserPass = pass;
}
 // create getter and setter to each one. 
 public UserNickName
  {
     get{return userName; } 
     set{ userName = value;}
  }
 // the same for all my getter and setter.
```

}
here is another class called handler

```
public handler{ // has object from DBManager.cs
DBManager db; 
public void userLogin(User u){ db.userLogin(u);}}
```

My last class is DBmanager

```
public DBManager{
 // constructor has the database connection and my login method
  public void userLogin(User user)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("uselogin",_conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("userNickName",     user.UserNickName);
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("userPassword", user.UserPassword);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        _conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (rd.HasRows)
        {
            rd.Read();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("PublishingAnEvent.aspx", true);
        }
        else
        {
          //  Label5.Text = "do it agin";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("RegestrationPage.aspx", true);
        }
```

}

I hope you give me the answer I did a lot of reading but I could not find anything.... Thanks to all of you.

Comment: are what point do you persist the results of the login? I don't see a forms authentication cookie being made, nor do I see any value being assigned in any aspect...

Comment: How I do forms authentication cookie ( Note: there is no level of login just an example of login) @BrettCaswell

Comment: north.star, (nice name btw).. FormAuthentication has a default Module loaded into ASP.NET and designate that ASP.NET handles the authentication in IIS. Most implementations I've seen override OnAuthenticate in the Global.asax.. they then create a cookie, and use the FormsAuthentication class to encrypt it.. On every `Page` request, there is a process that decrypts the cookie as assigns the user to `Request.User`.

Comment: review `FromsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie(v=vs.110).aspx there are in-page implementations..

Comment: actually, just review `FormAuthentication` Class  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication(v=vs.110).aspx

note that your method of using ADO.NET is to determine whether the user/pass credentials are valid (which is correct), and then you use `FormAuthentication` to persist it.. in the page example, it uses `MembershipProvider` (another Module) which you may or may not want to inherit and override to do the validating...

Comment: Thanks, I will @BrettCaswell

Comment: north.star, if you do decide to create your own MembershipProvider for your validating, note that a great many of the properties are to be set by your configuration settings; the reason why these are asp.net modules, is because they are commonly constructed out of the scope of your application but initialized (via initialization method) in your application. that inferred usage pattern is something to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing your homework for you, I do have the following insights:

1. You should always use the "owner" as part of the stored procedure's name
2. You should always use `using` blocks on anything that implements `IDisposable` (see my example shown below). This helps dispose of them easily and properly.
3. Instead of instantiating the connection in the constructor, I chose my pattern of using a method to do so. The method would instantiate and open the `SqlConnection` object, and it would handle all errors.
4. I changed the parameter creation to use a simpler method.
5. I took out the `rd.Read()` line because it did not seem to serve a purpose.

example:

```
    public DBManager
    {
        public void userLogin(User user)
        {
            using (SqlConnection _conn = GetConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.uselogin",_conn))
                {
                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userNickName", user.UserNickName);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userPassword", user.UserPassword);
                   using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                   {
                       if (rd.HasRows)
                       {
                           HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("PublishingAnEvent.aspx", true);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           //. Label5.Text = "do it again";
                           HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("RegistrationPage.aspx", true);
                       }
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
```